# Using the twig (standalone) i18n Extension with xliff files

Tags: symfony, internationalization, twig

I'd like to use the Twig template engine (as a standalone module without Symphony) with the i18n Extension.
By following the documentation (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html) I was able to run translations with .po and .mo files.

I'd like to manage translation with .xliff (xml) files. Is it possible with Twig only (without symphony) ?
I can't find any examples or documentation on translations management with xliff files and Twig as a standalone module.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`i18n` extension supports `po` files through `gettext`. Xliff which is a much more advanced and complex localization format is rarely supported out of the box in frameworks. Easiest method to tackle your problem would be to convert your `po` files to Xliff using [Okapi Tikal](http://www.opentag.com/okapi/wiki/index.php?title=tikal), do the translation in Xliff and then convert back.